# ERROR: "init terminating in do_boot" /usr/local/bin/elixir: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: elixir

I'm getting the following error (Error 1 below) sometimes when I try to run `mix test` or `iex`. Once I quit out of all Elixir related shell tasks and restart Terminal, it will work again (for a while). If I try to open up a new Terminal window and start the Elixir shell (before quitting out of other ones), I get ERROR 2. `erl` will always work, so I don't think it's an Erlang issue.

I'll also get a popup in Sublime Text that says `Resource temporarily unavailable` if I try to save a file while all of this is going on.

ERROR 1:

```
/usr/local/bin/elixir: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/usr/local/bin/erl: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{elixir,start_cli,[],[]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

ERROR 2:

```
/usr/local/bin/iex: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/usr/local/bin/iex: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/usr/local/bin/iex: line 42: /Users/USER/Documents/elixir: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/iex: line 42: exec: /Users/USER/Documents/elixir: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what could be causing this, or how to find out?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13010845/409228). It's nothing specific to Elixir or Erlang.

Comment: I've been having this error too, no resolution yet.  When I checked my running processes though I did have hundreds of zombie beam processes (~400) which I assume where not stopping when I CTRL-C during dev.