# Multiple fork calls cause BlockingIOError

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, fork

I'm searching for an explanation about the error I get with the following snippet :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            sys.exit()
        elif pid > 0:
            pass
            # os.waitpid(pid, 0)
        else:
            sys.exit()
```

This will spawn many processes (processes that exit as they are spawned).

This will eventually cause a `BlockingIOError` showing like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./asd.py", line 7, in <module>
    pid = os.fork()
BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

But when the `os.waitpid` call is uncommented, everything seems to be fine.

**Why does this error occurs and what does this `waitpid` call may change about it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same problem [whenever `fork` dies this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009632/getting-strange-behavior-from-terminal-and-iterm-bash-fork-resource-temporar); the error message is just how `EAGAIN` is conveyed to you:

1. You're out of memory or
2. You've hit the process limit (e.g. `RLIMIT_NPROC`)

`waitpid` fixes it because it reaps the zombie child processes; until you do that, those processes count towards the cap (it has to preserve them so the parent can look at the termination information).

You can see the various `fork` error codes documented on [its man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork).

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.
I have a programm that makes a lot of `fork` calls to spawn processes that may timeout.
In such case the processes were just killed by the parent process with os.kill (which, according to your answer isn't enough). If I understand your answer well, calling `waitpid()` for processes that timeouted as well.
But is there a function that would be meant to only "reap" these processes without retrieving informations,? (Since I don't need it because I know how the process terminated in such case).

Comment: @vmonteco: You can have the parent globally opt-out of handling child processes by [setting the `SIGCHLD` handler to `SIG_IGN` explicitly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process#Overview); Python provides access to signal handler settings in the `signal` module. This means you can't get the exit status of a child that has already exited though. There is also a double-`fork` + `setsid` solution to create daemon processes that has a similar effect (you can reap the intermediate child immediately, and the grandchild is detached).

Comment: I checked your comment and finally waitpid() seems to be the best solution (I still need to get the exit status of other processes, and setting up a grandchild process seems uselessly complicated). Yey your link learned me things, thank you again for that!