# BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable. What causes this?

Tags: python, fork

After the 115th iteration, sometimes more, an error appears:

`pid = os.fork() BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable`

Here is the program code:

```
for i in range(600):
    pid = os.fork()
    print(str(i) + " Create pid = " + str(pid) + " getpid =  " + str(os.getpid()))
    if pid == 0:
        print(str(i) + " Child process pid = " + str(pid) + " getpid =  " + str(os.getpid()))
        print(str(i) + " Kill pid = " + str(pid) + " getpid =  " + str(os.getpid()))
        os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
    else:
        print(str(i) + " Parent process pid = " + str(pid) + " getpid =  " + str(os.getpid()))
print(str(i) + " End process pid = " + str(pid) + " getpid =  " + str(os.getpid()))
```

I can't write os.waitpid, because it is necessary that when the loop interaction ends, the program does not stop, but continues to run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple fork calls cause BlockingIOError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534288/multiple-fork-calls-cause-blockingioerror)